# display every record on new line in php response

Tags: php, mysql

$sql_query = "select * from app_faculty";

```
    $result = mysql_query($sql_query) or die("Error : ".mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {      

         $summary_array["Id"]=$row["id"];
         $summary_array["Uid"]=$row["u_id"];
         $summary_array["Name"]=$row["name"];
         $summary_array["Detail"]=$row["detail"];
         $summary_array["Created_date"]=$row["created_date"];
         $summary_array["Updated_date"]=$row["updated_date"];
         $summary_array["Deleted"]=$row["deleted"];

         $business_array[] = $summary_array;


    }




$new_array["response"]= $business_array;    

$output = json_encode($new_array);

echo $output."<br />";
```

I want to display records from sql on new line after every { } brackets.
It should be displayed one after another and within [ ] brackets

Comment: user `var_dump` insted of `echo` '''

Comment: what is the output now? and what output you want?

Comment: {"response":[{"Id":"101","Name":"VTU","Detail":"ghgjg","Created_date":"2006-02-07","Updated_date":"2014-02-24","Deleted":"0"},{"Id":"101","Name":"VTU","Detail":"ghgjg","Created_date":"2006-02-07","Updated_date":"2014-02-24","Deleted":"0"}}]} I want every record with { } on new line